# Making POST request containing a list

Tags: java, scala, post

I've been trying to implement a Scala application which makes POST request to given REST web services. In the request, there is a list of strings. I try to use [scalaj](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) but it only allows params as the map from String to String.

So, I wonder if there is anyway to make a POST request containing the list of Strings in Scala, solutions in Java are also welcomed.

Comment: you want to do this with some std stuff or using some library?

Comment: I prefer library if it simplifies the process, otherwise, standard solution is fine :)

Comment: Take a look at [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) i think that's the easiest solution in Scala for you

Comment: I already look at it but it seems not to support sending list as well

Comment: in which format you want to send a list? Json?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly. As long as I can receive a list on server side, I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

After looking and trying around, I finally find the answer which is surprisingly simple. Although [scalaj](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) only allows Map from String to String, it also allows list of tuples. By keeping the same first value in the tuples, I can send the list of items.

For example, in order to send the list of numbers whose key is "data", I need to:

```
Http.post("http://localhost/Dummy").params("data" -> "1", "data" -> "2")
```